# Chimenea/Outdoor Fireplace Crack Repair Mortar-type

Tags: repair, fireplace, crack

I was trying to repair a cracked chiminea ( outdoor fireplace). I have "Quikkrete" quick-setting cement. I was wondering if this would be okay to use to patch and seal the cracks and hold against high temperatures when I have fires. Could someone please offer any advice on what type of pottery/clay sealing bondage product that is fire resistant, if I should not use this stuff and what maybe I should be using?? I'm not that knowledgeable with this kind of DIY home fix.

Comment: A picture may help.  FWIW, I’ve broken 2 chimeneas in the past, neither was repairable for fire purposes, one got glued and is now a planter the other one went to the dump.

Comment: Fire clay may be your best bet. It is designed for high heat and you may be able to make a patch that will hold.

Comment: is fire clay  ok for outdoors. Where temp change matters?  More worried about outside  in cold areas were frost may happen ?

Answer (score 1):

No, Portland cement products do not tolerate much heat. Hardware type stores should have some products for use on flue pipes .

Comment: I do think your wright ..But he has cement.

Comment: Looking at the input..Sounds like time to buy a new one..

Answer (score -1):

Of course mortar is heat resistant.

All the properties, cement, lime, sand, etc, are naturally heat resistant. However, mixing and applying the mortar can be enhanced by following a few extra steps. See link:

https://www.hunker.com/13401202/how-to-make-fireproof-mortar